# What is the mass of the sphere?

Tags: calculus

Let $K$ be a sphere with radius $R$ and let $\pi$ be a plane with distance $2R$ from the center of the sphere. The density of the sphere is $a$ where $a$ is is the distance from a point $P$ and $\pi$.

So I let $K$ be sphere with the center at the origin $(0,0,0)$. Further I let a point of the plane be $(0,0,2R)$. Thus the density function is $\rho=2R-z$ for points $P(x,y,z)$ within the sphere. The area of a disc of the sphere can be written as $A=\pi(R^2-z^2)$. So $M=2\pi\int^R_0(R^2-z^2)(2R-z)dz=2\pi\int^R_0(2R^3-R^2z-2Rz^2+z^3)dz=2\pi[2R^3z-\frac{R^2z^2}{2}-\frac{2Rz^3}{3}+\frac{z^4}{4}]^R_0=2R^4-\frac{R^4}{2}-\frac{2R^4}{3}+\frac{R^4}{4}=2\pi\frac{24R^4-6R^4-8R^4+3R^4}{12}=\pi\frac{13R^4}{6}$. The answer should be $\pi\frac{8R^4}{3}$. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake here is assuming that $(R^2-z^2)(2R-z)$ is an even function.

Your integral should instead read $M = \pi \int_{-R}^R (R^2-z^2) (2R-z) \text{d}z$, rather than the integral from $0$ to $R$ doubled.

Solving this gives your $\frac{8}{3}\pi R^4$, as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You did only half of the computations you need to compute $$\int_{-R}^0 \ldots \; dz$$

Comment: wow im retarded